# Caffe how to pass custom loss function to net.backward()

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, caffe

Caffe notes that

> The backward pass computes the gradient given the loss for learning[...]

However you can call

```
net.backward()
```

and still get the diffs without even passing any expected output. I want to compute the gradient with respect to the input and my own loss function. How do I do this in Caffe?

Comment: if your loss layer is already part of the `net`, then the gradient is computed with respect to that loss.

Comment: @Shai I am using a pretrained model, how can I add a loss layer?